# ExtensionMethods for iterating hierarchically data structures depth/breath-first

Tags: c#, iterator, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, extension-methods

I wrote a few simple extension methods that allow to traverse a hierachically data structure depth-first or breath-first using LINQ:

**Usage:**

```
public class Item
{
    public Item(string name, params Item[] children)
    {
        Name = name;
        Items = (children ?? new Item[0]).ToList();
    }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; private set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var hierachicalItems = new[]
                {
                    new Item("A1",
                        new Item("B1",
                            new Item("C1"),
                            new Item("C2")),
                        new Item("B2"))
                };                  

    var query = hierachicalItems.DepthFirst(i => i.Items).Select(i => i.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("DepthFirst:\t\t" + string.Join(", ", query));

    query = hierachicalItems.BreadthFirst(i => i.Items).Select(i => i.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("BreadthFirst:\t" + string.Join(", ", query));
}
```

> **Output:**
>
> DepthFirst:    A1, B1, C1, C2, B2
>
> BreadthFirst:  A1, B1, B2, C1, C2

**The TreeEnumerable class:**

```
public static class TreeEnumerable
{
    // BreathFirst
    // ==========================================================

    public static IEnumerable<TNode> BreadthFirst<TNode>(this IEnumerable<TNode> nodes,
        Func<TNode, IEnumerable<TNode>> getSubNodes)
    {
        Queue<TNode> queue = new Queue<TNode>(256);

        foreach (TNode node in nodes)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(node);
        }

        return BreadthFirst(queue, getSubNodes);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<TNode> BreadthFirst<TNode>(Queue<TNode> queue,
        Func<TNode, IEnumerable<TNode>> getSubNodes)
    {
        TNode node;

        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            node = queue.Dequeue();

            if (node == null)
            {
                yield break;
            }

            foreach (TNode subNode in getSubNodes(node))
            {
                queue.Enqueue(subNode);
            }

            yield return node;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TNode> BreadthFirst<TNode>(this IEnumerable<TNode> nodes,
        Func<TNode, IEnumerable<TNode>> getSubNodes,
        Boolean repeatNodes)
    {
        HashSet<TNode> passedNodes = new HashSet<TNode>();
        Queue<TNode> queue = new Queue<TNode>(256);

        if (repeatNodes)
        {
            return nodes.BreadthFirst(getSubNodes);
        }

        foreach (TNode node in nodes)
        {
            if (passedNodes.Contains(node))
            {
                continue;
            }

            passedNodes.Add(node);

            queue.Enqueue(node);
        }

        return BreadthFirst(queue, getSubNodes, passedNodes);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<TNode> BreadthFirst<TNode>(Queue<TNode> queue,
        Func<TNode, IEnumerable<TNode>> getSubNodes,
        HashSet<TNode> passedNodes)
    {
        TNode node;

        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            node = queue.Dequeue();

            if (node == null)
            {
                yield break;
            }

            foreach (TNode subNode in getSubNodes(node))
            {
                if (passedNodes.Contains(subNode))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                passedNodes.Add(subNode);

                queue.Enqueue(subNode);
            }

            yield return node;
        }
    }

    // DepthFirst
    // ==========================================================

    public static IEnumerable<TNode> DepthFirst<TNode>(this IEnumerable<TNode> nodes,
        Func<TNode, IEnumerable<TNode>> getSubNodes)
    {
        foreach (TNode node in nodes)
        {
            yield return node;

            foreach (TNode subNode in getSubNodes(node).DepthFirst(getSubNodes))
            {
                yield return subNode;
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TNode> DepthFirst<TNode>(this IEnumerable<TNode> nodes,
        Func<TNode, IEnumerable<TNode>> getSubNodes,
        Boolean repeatNodes)
    {
        if (repeatNodes)
        {
            return nodes.DepthFirst(getSubNodes);
        }

        return nodes.DepthFirst(getSubNodes, new HashSet<TNode>());
    }

    private static IEnumerable<TNode> DepthFirst<TNode>(this IEnumerable<TNode> nodes,
        Func<TNode, IEnumerable<TNode>> getSubNodes,
        HashSet<TNode> passedNodes)
    {
        foreach (TNode node in nodes)
        {
            if (passedNodes.Contains(node))
            {
                continue;
            }

            passedNodes.Add(node);

            yield return node;

            foreach (TNode subNode in getSubNodes(node).DepthFirst(getSubNodes, passedNodes))
            {
                yield return subNode;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any improvments or usefull enhancement?

Comment: Yep, I have suggestion. It would be great timesaver if it could run not only over lists of children but also enumerate object properties and their values and subobjects... something like linqpad's dump

Comment: Ok, interesting idea. However the use case seems to be a little bit different. A "linqpad dump iterator" have to return a more general object that can not be used directly... a list of `KeyValue<string, object>` pairs where each value may be another list of `KeyValue<string, object>` pairs or something like that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Items = (children ?? new Item[0]).ToList();
```

In C# 6.0, you can write it like this:

```
Items = children?.ToList() ?? new List<Item>();
```

---

```
// BreathFirst
// ==========================================================
```

Consider using `#region` instead?

Also, typo: BreathFirst.

---

```
TNode node;
```

No need to declare the variable here, outside the loop.

---

```
if (node == null)
{
    yield break;
}
```

Why does `null` node mean "stop iterating"?

---

```
HashSet<TNode> passedNodes = new HashSet<TNode>();
Queue<TNode> queue = new Queue<TNode>(256);

if (repeatNodes)
{
    return nodes.BreadthFirst(getSubNodes);
}
```

Why are you creating the two collections before you know whether you will need them?

---

```
if (passedNodes.Contains(node))
{
    continue;
}

passedNodes.Add(node);

queue.Enqueue(node);
```

You can take advantage of the fact that `HashSet<T>.Add()` returns a `bool` indicating whether the item was added and simplify this to:

```
if (passedNodes.Add(node))
{
    queue.Enqueue(node);
}
```

---

```
foreach (TNode subNode in getSubNodes(node).DepthFirst(getSubNodes))
{
    yield return subNode;
}
```

Keep in mind that this is going to have pretty bad time complexity (quadratic) if the depth of the tree becomes large enough. If performance matters, consider using approach similar to `BreadthFirst`, only with `Stack` instead of `Queue`.

Comment: Thanks for the great review! I agree with all of your points. However, could you please explain the last one? I dont understand why the "depth first" approach has bad time complexity compared to the "breadth first" approach.

Comment: @JanDotNet See for example [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michste/archive/2011/09/26/lack-of-nested-iterators-in-c.aspx).